# Azure function seems to be running fine on App Service plan but Azure warns that "Storage is not configured properly"

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I have a few Azure functions that process Service Bus messages. They seem to work just fine, messages are processed as expected.

However, all of these functions display a warning in Azure:

> Storage is not configured properly, Function scaling will be limited.
> Click to learn more.

The link leads to an article with advice to check that the storage account is running. I see it exists and has tables, blobs, and queues.

I have deployed my functions through ARM template with the following settings:

```
            "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
            "AzureWebJobsStorage": "[format(variables('kv_secrets'), 'AzureWebJobsStorage')]",
```

`kv_secrets` is a custom template variable that references Azure Key vault.

When looking in the deployed func configuration on Azure, it seems to be picked up just fine, no errors, storage account itself also works and functions work.

How to fix that warning? Is that Azure's mistake or will there be a real impact on my functions if I don't fix it?

Comment: Are you using free Trial Subscription ?

Comment: Are you, in the end, using Key Vault References to access the `AzureWebJobsStorage` setting? And is the storage account publicly available?

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT no, it's a paid subscription.

Comment: Look your storage account name in your application settings.
Either `AzureWebJobsStorage` or `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` contains the name of your storage account as part of a connection string.

Comment: Put the Connection String (without ;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net) in `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` and the functions name in `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE`.

Comment: @rickvdbosch I can connect to the storage from Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer app using the same connection string that is inside the keyvault variable, so it looks fine.

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT  Thanks, I can try that. Although Microsoft documentation says that these WEBSITE_ variables are not needed for functions hosted as App Services.

Comment: which  paid subscription you are using ?

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT  It's "Enterprise Dev/Test" (OfferId=MS-AZR-0148P) of my employer company.